# How does sling selectors work?

Tags: aem, sling, client-library

I am working on [HTTP caching](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching#invalidating-and-updating-cached-responses) and to implement cache busting, I am using ACS [Versioned ClientLibs](https://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/features/versioned-clientlibs.html). Now this works fine for js file when it is part of clientlib. For example `<script src="/etc/designs/myapp/clientlibs/base.js">` works. But when I try to access an individual js within the library it doesnt work. For example `<script src="/etc/designs/myapp/clientlibs/base/js/app1.js">` fails. The reason is the MD5 hash added as sling selector gets resolved when it is a clientlib js. But selector is not getting resolved when calling js individually. `</base.hash.js>` works but `</base/js/app1.hash.js>` fails.

How does AEM know to resolve selectors when calling clientlibs and doesnt do when calling individual js?

And the reason I need selectors to work specifically is, as per [PageSpeed](https://gtmetrix.com/remove-query-strings-from-static-resources.html), most proxies donot cache static references with ? param. And asks to remove the query params. So I cant add query param for cache busting.

Comment: Not 100% sure, thus only as a comment and not as an answer: The combined js files are processed by AEM before it is returned and thus the hash is taken into account. The individual files seem to be sent back as a plain binaries without any processing.

Comment: Yeah.. thats wat I too infer. But if someone throws light on whats happening, probably could think of some hotfix to work around the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/etc/designs/myapp/clientlibs/base is a 
cq:ClientLibraryResource

/etc/designs/myapp/clientlibs/base/js/app.js is a nt:file resource.

There is no resource .../base/js/app this you can't request this resource w a selector (app.hash.js)

Comment: This is the closest answer I could get that resource resolver can parse the sling selectors only when it is a [HTMLLibrary](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/javadoc/com/day/cq/widget/HtmlLibrary.html). In case of jcr:primaryType:nt:file, it fails to resolve as HTMLLibrary and resource resolver simply returns full text as resolved which fails ultimately. And solution to my problem am writing dispatcher rewriter to strip out selectors.